# Eclipse C++ build problem

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, ubuntu, build-process

I've just written a simple program in C++ in Eclipse on Ubuntu. But when I press Ctrl+B or select the build all button no binary file is build, and so when I try to run the project I receive the error message: Launch failed. binary not found.

what should I do?

thanx!

Comment: Are there any compile/build problems?

Comment: No I receive no error when building the project

Comment: What are the message in the console in Eclipse ?

Comment: what do you mean? at the build time, of course, nothing is written in the console. And when trying to run, the error message is not written in the console too.

Comment: Are you on a 64-bit OS like Snow Leopard? If so then you might need to give a flag to the compiler to say so.

Comment: Oh ok, I see you're on ubuntu. Is it a 64-bit ubuntu?

Comment: What happens when you manually compile your program with g++ at the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You can compile and run the program in the terminal

Go to the specific directory in the terminal using the cd command and type

```
g++ <filename>.cpp -o <filename> # This compiles the code
./<filename> # Runs the program in the terminal
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to manually configure the 'run configuration' you use to run the program to find the binary to execute. If there are no compilation errors, it should have created an executable somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

My Binaries were found under Default package instead of the expected "Debug" package. I had to manually modify run configuration (as mentioned by ascanio). I had to change the path of the application that's all.